# SQL - Multiple owned items

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a MySQL Database. I've got a table containing basic information of people looking like this:

**MySQL**

```
create table TBL_Pers (
Clientnr        int,
Name            varchar,
Post            char(6),
Cont            char(1),
Contdr          tinyint,
p_p_a           smallmoney)
```

Moving on, I have got a table with info about the printers in the database like so:

**MySQL**

```
create table TBL_Printer (
PNr             int,
PBrand          varchar,
PName           varchar,
Serialnr        varchar)
```

So here comes my question:

Let's say we have 3 different kinds of printers in TBL_Printer and a person owns 2 of them. How do I fill in that information in TBL_Pers so I can extract that information with PHP (To generate the owned printers in a overview on a webpage)?

Comment: BTW `identity` is not MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another table to relate both

```
CREATE TABLE person_printer
(
   person  int not null,
   printer int not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (person, printer)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better add a third table to connect these two tables.But if you only have three kind of printer you just need to add three colums to the TBL_Pers for each printer.If he or she owns one "1" to the column else fill "0".